# How to compile using framework libraries?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, .net-2.0

I have wrriten a managed code for SMO application.How can i comiled it using

.NETFRAMEWORK2.0. i dont wnat to use visulastudio due to  certain limitataions.

how can i do this. can nay body help me in this regard.

msbuild.exe TestMsBuild.sln /:t Rebuild /:p configuration=release  gives  error as

TestMsBuild.sln : Solution file error MSB4054: The solution file must be opened
in the Visual Studio IDE and converted to the latest version before it can be bu
ilt by MSBuild.

even though my project is opend i got this error But as it shows i dont know how to convert to latest version

Comment: "msbuild.exe test.sln /:t Rebuild /:p configauration=release gives some error" - what error does it give? (you are aware that the word "configauration" in that command line is spelled wrong? It should be "configuration")

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you misspelled "configuration?" If not that, then it might be your code. Without more information it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're using VS2008 to compile a VS2005 solution (or 2005 to compile a 2003 one). Open the solution in VS2008, go through the upgrade wizard, save changes, close VS2008 and try the command line again.