# How to Compile a c++ program using .NET Framework libraries

Tags: c++-cli, .net-2.0

i want comile a my c++ program using .NETFRAMEWORK libraries only at command prompt.how can i do this ??

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861949/how-to-compile-using-framework-libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Download the free [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vc/) tools from Microsoft and use the C++/CLI language (based on C++ but allows access to the whole .Net Framework) and go from there.

Comment: I have alredy .NET framework installed .then y another tools???

supose for c# there is csc compiler in .NETFRAmework libraries.

c:\windows\microsft .netframewor\2.0.57\lib\scs like wise....

Comment: I can't tell if you're asking a question or just complaining incoherently.  Basically, if you already have cl.exe you have the compiler, otherwise install a package (there are many) that contains it.

Comment: My understanding is that only the VC compiler can compiple C++/CLI which is the only (simple) way of getting to managed code from C++. It is not shipped as part of the .Net runtime/SDK unlike the C#/VB compilers, so you need to download it. The Visual C++ Express is a free and easy way to doo this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're talking about [Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw(VS.80).aspx).  As for using the command prompt, once you have a working program you should just be able to use something like:

```
cl MyProgram.cs /clr
```

with any other relevant options, and be up and running.  If that doesn't help, give a more specific question.